# Cache folders taking a lot of space: store_00010001/Pictures/cache/com.google.android.googlephotos/picasa--{0,1,2...}

Tags: internal-storage, optimization

I've found that this cache folders take 1,5GiB of my 16GB Nexus 5:
`store_00010001/Pictures/cache/com.google.android.googlephotos/picasa--{0,1,2...}`

Is it cache of some app, which I can easily remove from phone level? (App settings -> clear data/cache?)
Or do I have to clear it from computer periodically?

Answer (score 3):

### solution: block with empty file

block folder creation with an empty file

on my phone i created this empty file

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/cache
```

### size

that folder was 7 g on my phone

https://plus.google.com/photos/yourphotos say "3306 photos"

### recreated daily

if i deleted the folder, it reappeared the next day

### side effect

no side effects noticed by using this solution

auto backup still works

### system

tested on my nexus 5

Answer (score 2):

I was just having this same issue and found that I had to clear the cache data for the Gallery (which you have to get to in Settings->Application Manager->All->Gallery). This cleared up over 1GB of space for me on my internal card.

**Note**: I used an app called Memory Map to get a visual representation to see what was taking up so much space on my internal storage since it was originally just a Google alert telling me I was out of space.

Answer (score 1):

You may install [App Cache Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.cache) application. One of the feature is "auto clear all cache at a specified interval".

Configure it once and it will never let the cache grow such large.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can clear Photos's cache from the phone itself.

Comment: Do you mean "App Info" of G+ Photos app , than "clear cache"?

Comment: Yep. But why is the cache that big?

Comment: And why can't I set a limit of size of this cache?  I guess that it's that bug because it's making thumbnails of all G+ photos and those are much more than photos on camera... but that's my quess.